# How to align a li tag vertically

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How i can align to center my "li" tag?

```
    const succes = <a href="#" className='succes'>✓</a>
    const fail = <a href="#" className="fail"></a>
   

   <div className="goals">
      <li>Collect 5 thousand subscribers</li>
      <li>Learn ReactJS </li>
      <li>{succes} Move to apartment</li>
      <li>Start speaking english fluently</li>
  </div>
```

I need something like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y2VX.jpg

Comment: Are you using `text-align: center` on `li` tag?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid for a start. `li` can not be a direct child of `div`, the only valid parents are `ol`, `ul` or `menu`

Comment: Please include your CSS or better still a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping all of your list items in a UL element:

```
 <div className="goals">
      <ul>
      <li>Collect 5 thousand subscribers</li>
      <li>Learn ReactJS </li>
      <li>{succes} Move to apartment</li>
      <li>Start speaking english fluently</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Generally speaking you should always use a list tag to start and close any lists that you are using.

Take a look at this for further clarification:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

It also may also depend on your CSS too so double check that as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put `li` in `ul`
2. Check what `goals` class has. Does it have `text-align:center`?

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>

<div class="centered">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</div>

<!-- UL vs DIV -->
<ul class="centered">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't, in good faith, upvote an answer with invalid HTML.  [`div` is not a vaild parent for `li`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

Comment: If you just had said, *div is not valid parent for li*; this would have been fine. My objection is to your narcissism that you need to tell others why you DIDN'T do something as trivial as clicking a button.

Comment: Perhaps familiarize yourself with: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language

Comment: At the end of the day I was trying to help you out and stop the OP from following potentially bad advise regarding the invalid html

Answer (score 0):

You could just nest another `<ul>` in between, like

```
<div className="goals">
 <ul>
  <li>Collect 5 thousand subscribers</li>
  <li style="list-style: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Learn ReactJS </li>
      <li>{succes} Move to apartment</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Start speaking english fluently</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Some more invalid HTML here. The only valid child of `ul` is `li`. If you are going to nest `ul` the nested `ul` must be in an `li`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that you can't put a `li` directly inside a `div`, because it is not allowed for some reason. You should put it in a `ul` instead to keep the validators happy. Like this:

```html
<div className="goals"> 
    <ul>
        <li>Collect 5 thousand subscribers</li> 
        <li>Learn ReactJS </li> 
        <li>{succes} Move to apartment</li> 
        <li>Start speaking english fluently</li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

We can then use a bit of flexbox to center this `ul`:

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This should hopefully center it! Hooray!